# WebRTC and UDP port detection

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, webrtc

I would like to know if it's possible to use the WebRTC Data Channel to infer whether or not a UDP port is open.

Comment: While there's no technical restriction to using WebRTC server-side (it's just another peer), WebRTC solves problems specific to P2P communication, which is completely unnecessary for browser-server scenarios. You already have both HTTP and web sockets for browser-server communication. Why do you want WebRTC instead?

Comment: @Daniel Fair enough if mocking a peer is the intent here. Using a headless browser would do fine for such a scenario as well. The OP makes it sound like they're trying to use it beyond testing though.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Agree we could use HTTP and web sockets to communicate between the browser and server.  Just curious.  Do you think it would be possible to send a WebRTC data stream (in unreliable mode) from the browser to a particular port on the server.  If the server received the data stream, wouldn't that imply the particular UDP port is open.  I know this is a weird and roundabout way of doing things, but I'm looking for an explanation of why this wouldn't work.

Comment: First of all you would need to establish a WebRTC connection, which involves relaying messages between the involved peers... for that you need, uhm, a connection to a server which can relay those messages between the yet unconnected peers. In this case, the server would need to relay a bunch of messages to you so you can establish a connection to exchange messages... which, uhm, is quite nonsensical. It's not that it can't work, it's that it makes little sense.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation.  Yes the signaling server would need to do exactly as you described.  Would it be fair to say that this approach is simply overly-involved for the purpose of checking a UDP port?  The reason this approach was investigated is because there didn't seem to be any other way of checking a UDP port when the user initiates this check from the browser.

Comment: This is probably the entirely wrong tool for the purpose of checking whether a UDP port is open.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I believe we can say that since the WebRTC Data Channel uses the SCTP protocol (rather than UDP), UDP port detection won't work.